# Why does this Embed.set_footer call fail in my Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, chatbot

I send nearly all bot output via embeds, using the below method:

````
async def show_message_embed(self, ctx: commands.Context, message, title=None):
    if title is None:
        title = f"Command Output"
    em = discord.Embed(title=title, description="```\n" + message + "\n```", colour=0xBD362F)
    #em.set_footer("ChatNote (c) 2020 Erisia")
    em.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
````

The `#em.set_footer` line is commented out because if I uncomment it, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: set_footer() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am quite obviously, to me, only passing 1 positional argument - the only argument, so what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`set_footer`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.set_footer) takes `text` as a parameter and an optional `icon_url`.

```
em.set_footer(text="ChatNote (c) 2020 Erisia")
```